# My bootstrap drop-down items are not clickable (showing)

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

Anytime I include a link to bootstrap.min.css lying locally in my Django project, my drop-down menu becomes non-clickable. Am a learning Django with no much knowledge of bootstrap. The tutorial am following used cdn to include the bootstrap but I downloaded it manually because of internet connection. Although the downloaded bootstrap is working but the drop-down menu is not working. Can someone help me out.. I can't continue learning at this stage. Thanks in advance.
The code is below.

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
    <!-- Required meta tags --> 
    <meta charset="utf-"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" 
    integrity="sha-MCw/SFnGEfJTGXwEOngsVZtNXFoaoApmYmi\ uXoPkFOJwJERdknLPMO" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">


    <title>{% block title %}Newspaper App{% endblock title %}</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-"> 
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Newspaper</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
                data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" 
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button> 
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse"> 
                {% if user.is_authenticated %} 
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"> 
                        <li class="nav-item"> 
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown "href="#" id="userMenu"
                                aria-expanded="false"> 
                                {{ user.username }} 
                            </a> 
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" 
                                aria-labelledby="userMenu"> 
                                <a class="dropdown-item" 
                                href="{% url 'password_change'%}">Change password</a> 
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> 
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}"> 
                                    Log Out</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                {% else %}
                    <form class="form-inline ml-auto"> 
                        <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"> 
                        Log In</a> 
                        <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary ml-">
                        Sign up</a> 
                    </form>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container"> 
            {% block content %} 
            {% endblock content %}
        </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript --> 
   <!-- <jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-...slim.min.js" integrity="sha-qi/X+DzOrTabKJStQIAqVgRVzpbzosmXKp\ YfRvH+abtTEPijizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/\ ../ umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha-ZMPrVomIykV++JUJjBkWLaUAdnaCwoqbB\ JiSnjAK/ lWvCWPIPm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" 
    integrity="sha-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK+MXmPNIyEZbWhIMqErYiqJxyMiZ\ OW/JmZQstwEULTy" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body> 
</html>
```

```
#settings.py
"""
Django settings for helloworld_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'z0qdn^sf&ill&gg%3myb#q)bzp$!^xnn-3(1po+blyjt1(bxyv'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    #local
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig',
    #'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    #'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    #'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
    #'page.apps.PageConfig',

    # 3rd Party
    'crispy_forms',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Lagos'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'helloworld_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'helloworld_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
'''EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net' 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_sendgrid_password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
#ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
'''
```

```
#views.py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

# Create your views here.


class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html
```

The login ,logout, etc are in templates/registration/

```
#project_urls.py
"""helloworld_project URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),

    #path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    #path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    #path('', include('blog.urls')),
    #path('', include('posts.urls')),
    #path('', include('page.urls')),
    #path('', include('pages.urls')),

]
```

And finally below is app_level url

```
#app_urls.py
from django.urls import path


from .views import SignUpView


urlpatterns = [
    path('signup', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the Jquery and Popper JS and put it in static folder

Comment: I have done that and it's not still working. I stored the jQuery.min.js and popper.min.js and bootstrap.min.js in my_project/static/J's
and loaded it to my template but it's not still working.

Comment: remove the integrity attribute on the script tag

Comment: can you please show us your views,py, urls.py and settings.py?

Comment: since the debug  mode = True,  try first to remove the STATIC_ROOT (just comment it out) or you can use the  command `python manage.py collectstatic` and put your files on the `staticfiles/` folder

Comment: I uncommented the STATIC_URL and it didn't work. I removed the comment and ran python manage.py collecstatic and it didn't still work. Pls what do you think next which comment do I use to collect static back to static folder

Comment: No error at all. The menu bar worked. The css style I applied worked. The only issue is the dropdown. When I click on the item to display dropdown, it simple reveals nothing but the link on my browser then becomes localhost/#

Answer (score 0):

I once had an issue like this:
I hope my solution works for you.

The jquery library (jquery-.slim.min.js) you are using in your html file may not contain the functions necessary to create the dropdown effect use the jquery.min.js instead.

Remove this from your html file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-...slim.min.js" integrity="sha-qi/X+DzOrTabKJStQIAqVgRVzpbzosmXKp\ YfRvH+abtTEPijizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And Use the jquery.min below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Connect to the internet and refresh.

P:S
You can as well download the jquery.min.js by going to this [jquery](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js), it's just about 87kb. Then copy the code and save it as jquery.min.js in your static folder and connect it in your template like this:

```
<script src="{% static 'jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
```

And you won't need internet again to use it. I think the jquery library you used is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before.
How I solved it was simply placing Jquery, then Popper js, followed by Boostrap js --- in that order.
I discovered the dropdown feature was dependent on Popper and Jquery.

Looking at your code, I see you followed that order, but I am not sure of the way you loaded boostrap using django.

Kindly get boostrap cdn, (same place you got Popper and Jquery), restart your server,  clear browser cache with SHIFT + F5 and try again.

Make sure you have internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error on line 23. Semicolon was wrongly placed by me. [image][image][image: This is what happened at line 23]